# XAML Xamarin OnPlatform Binding

Tags: xaml, exception, xamarin, binding, arguments

I think my code is self explanatory:

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource labelStyle}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding message}">
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>
          {DynamicResource rightBubbleFontColor}
        </OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>
            {DynamicResource rightBubbleFontColor}
        </OnPlatform.Android>
          <OnPlatform.Android>
            {StaticResource rightBubbleFontColor}
        </OnPlatform.Android>
      </OnPlatform>
    </Label>
```

I'm trying to dynamically bind a color to the label. Depending on the current platform, it has to be another type of resource (DynamicResource or StaticResource).

I get this exception when trying to build the solution:

`System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.`

### UPDATE

I now have this code:

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource labelStyle}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding message}">
      <Label.TextColor>
        <OnPlatform 
          x:Key="RightBubbleFontColor" 
          x:TypeArguments="Color"
          iOS="{DynamicResource rightBubbleFontColor}"
          Android="{DynamicResource rightBubbleFontColor}"
          WinPhone="{StaticResource rightBubbleFontColor}">
        </OnPlatform>
      </Label.TextColor>
    </Label>
```

And I get the following error message:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

When I replace the binding to a color it works.

Working example:

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource labelStyle}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding message}">
      <Label.TextColor>
        <OnPlatform 
          x:Key="RightBubbleFontColor" 
          x:TypeArguments="Color"
          iOS="Red"
          Android="Green"
          WinPhone="Blue">
        </OnPlatform>
      </Label.TextColor>
    </Label>
```

So it has to be an issue with the way I'm trying to bind this I guess.

### EDIT

Asked a new question to describe the problem better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852888/xamarin-forms-use-dynamicresource-or-staticresource-depending-on-os

Comment: Looks like the DynamicResource issue is something that's been around since at least April...

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65252/dynamicresource-limitation-for-onplatform-in-xaml-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `<OnPlatform.Android>` elements. I'm assuming the last would be `<OnPlatform.WinPhone>`.

**EDITED**

Now that you have that fixed, maybe try this for it to actually work?

```
<OnPlatform 
   x:Key="BubbleTextColor" 
   x:TypedArguments="Color"
   iOS="{DynamicResource rightBubbleFontColor}"
   Android="{DynamicResource rightBubbleFontColor}"
   WinPhone="{StaticResource rightBubbleFontColor}" />
```

Then bind it where necessary.

Not sure if it will work any differently than what you already have, but I guess it's worth a shot.

Comment: Oops right, thank you. Exception is gone and I can compile my project now, but the messages won't show. I guess the binding didn't work so the text has no color and thus is is invisible.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I updated my question

Comment: I would probably ask the question again in a new post, since the question has now changed.

Comment: Hi... Just guessing here, but I don't think the OnPlatform properties are bindable, that might be why it is failing. Is it possible to use a converter? As I said, I am guessing so my logic my be wrong

Comment: @Matthew isn't using a converter just the same (**binding** to a converter)?

Comment: I asked a new question and described the problem better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852888/xamarin-forms-use-dynamicresource-or-staticresource-depending-on-os